# How to structure very irregular structures by using pandas

Tags: pandas

Using pandas, is there a code way to extract output from input as shown below?

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

data = [['Loc','1',np.nan],['col1','col2','col3'],['b','c','d'],
['Loc','2',np.nan],['col1','col2','col3'],['e','f','g']]

df_input=pd.DataFrame(data)

data1=[['1','b','c','d'],['2','e','f','g']]

df_output=pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Loc','col1','col2','col3'])

df_input

df_output
```

Comment: Is the "header" value always "Loc"? are there always 3 columns with a NaN in the third one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the subheaders are always the first 2 rows of each group and that the groups can be identified by the presence of "Loc" in the first column  (or NaN in the third one), then use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df_input[0].eq('Loc')  # df_input[2].isna()

out = pd.concat({k: g.iloc[2:].set_axis(g.iloc[1], axis=1)
                     .assign(**{g.iat[0, 0]: g.iat[0, 1]})
                 for k, g in df_input.groupby(m.cumsum())}
                )#.droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
    col1 col2 col3 Loc
1 2    b    c    d   1
2 5    e    f    g   2
```

Or if don't care about the original index:

```
m = df_input[0].eq('Loc')  # df_input[2].isna()

out = pd.concat([g.iloc[2:].set_axis(g.iloc[1], axis=1)
                  .assign(**{g.iat[0, 0]: g.iat[0, 1]})
                 for k, g in df_input.groupby(m.cumsum())],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 Loc
0    b    c    d   1
1    e    f    g   2
```